# Concatenated SQL Column returning null value, is there a work around?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listbox

I have a sql statement that concatenates two columns, ItemNumber and Name, into one variable. I use this variable as the DataTextField for a listbox. Everything seemed to work great. I did find a problem though.. Some of the rows have a null value in the Name field, and when it returns the variable, the variable is null.

So I am asking if there is any way to check for that null value and instead put just the item number in its place?

Here is my SQL statement

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, CustItemNum, CustItemNum + ' - ' + Name AS itemNumName
FROM Item it inner join JITVendors jit on it.Catalog_code = jit.Catalog_code 
WHERE jit.VendorName = 'Vendor' 
ORDER BY Name
```

If there is any other code that could be helpful let me know and I will be able to provide it. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace a `null` name with an empty string:

```
CustItemNum + coalesce(' - ' + Name,'') AS itemNumName
```

Comment: Similarly, you can use `ISNULL` with the same syntax and semantics.

Comment: as soon as the 10 min period is over this will be marked.
Thank you for you response

Answer (score 3):

As @ashes999 suggested in the comments, you can use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, CustItemNum, ISNULL(CustItemNum,'') + ' - ' + ISNULL(Name,'') AS itemNumName
FROM Item it inner join JITVendors jit on it.Catalog_code = jit.Catalog_code 
WHERE jit.VendorName = 'Vendor' 
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned yet, if you want to do this everywhere without manually coalescing empty string every time:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
```

(Default is on). When on, concatenating NULL to a string yields NULL. When off, this server option treats it like empty string when concatenating strings together (e.g. any string concatenated to NULL when this is off will yield the original string).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx

Comment: I was not aware of that setting, so +1 for mentioning something new. Off to read the BOL :)

Comment: @Leigh I'd normally use one of the other answers here, but it came to my mind, thought I'd throw it out there! :-)

Comment: I typically use the others too, but I can see this setting being useful in special cases. One more tool for the arsenal, yay! :)